# Oracle script to do an arithmetic operation on column by column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Below is the requirement for an oracle script.
if C1 , C2 , C3 ... are columns in a table T

When I enter the table name T to the script , it should give the output as

```
C1 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(C1))/COUNT(C1)
C2 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(C2))/COUNT(C2)
C3 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(C3))/COUNT(C3)
```

I tried writing a procedure with a cursor in it which gets the names of columns one by one from the USER_TAB_COLUMNS

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1(TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR) AS 

DECLARE 
col varchar2(30)
cursor c1 as select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name ='TABLE_NAME';
open c1;
BEGIN 
Select c1 into col from USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='TABLE_NAME'

END
```

After this I got lost. I am new to this. Please help me with a solution to this problem. I am unable to proceed. Any approach is appreciated.

When the name of the table is entered, the output should be the list of the columns and the values as shown in the arithmetic operation.

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) to use dynamic table name.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Sylvain you need Dynamic SQL, specifically the DBMS_SQL package. I would use this technique to construct a new sql statement and then execute it with the easier to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
DECLARE
  c           NUMBER;
  d           NUMBER;
  col_cnt     INTEGER;
  rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  col_num    NUMBER;

 BEGIN

 c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

 DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'SELECT * FROM scott.bonus', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

 d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);

 DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);

 FOR col_num IN 1..col_cnt
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column Name:' || rec_tab.col_name);
      /* Build your new SQL statement here */
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);

  END;
```

See [Example 8](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68199) in the Oracle documentation for more details.